# Where is my new apk after using ./addSecurityExceptions.sh?

Tags: android

I used ./addSecurityExceptions.sh on a test.apk
It seems to go well but after the end of the process:
*(...)
jar signed.
Warning:
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
./addSecurityExceptions.sh: line 52: zipalign: command not found
Resigned APK successfully test_new.apk*

I don't find test_new.apk in the file, neither in my whole computer :o

Did someone has this case already?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to add the paths to the directories with the executable files zipalign.exe and jarsigner.exe to the Path environment variable.

- C:\Users\ @youruser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.2
- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXxJL.png)